# Largest Prime Factor Ruby using Fermat's factorization method

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have this code that seems to be working for number 6-8 digits, in a normal time period.
When I enter bigger values the amount get ridiculously bug. It takes more than 4 hours to complete.
Here is my code.

```
#Fermat's factorization method

def get_largest_prime n
    t=(Math.sqrt(n)+1).floor
    k=0
    prime_numbers=[]
    while (t+k)<n
        element = (t+k)**2-n
        if is_integer? Math.sqrt(element)
            #store prime numbers
            prime_numbers << t+k+Math.sqrt(element)
            prime_numbers << t+k-Math.sqrt(element) 
            #puts "Prime Factors of #{n} are: #{t+k+Math.sqrt(element)} and #{t+k-Math.sqrt(element)}"
        end
        k+=1
    end
  puts "Prime Factors: "+prime_numbers.to_s 
end

#making sure 450.0 is 450, for example.
def is_integer? number
    number.to_i == number ? true : false
end

get_largest_prime 600851475143
```

Running this will take more than 4 hours.

But running it for value ' 600851' for example or ' 60085167' does not take a lot of time. Any help ?

Comment: 1. That's like saying "I want to compress a 5GB file into 5MB 2. You waited 4 hours?!

Answer (score 2):

First note that Fermat factorisation doesn't give you prime factors in general.

Then, you run it until `t+k >= n`, that means you run the `while` loop `n - t` times, since `t` is roughly `sqrt(n)`, that is an `O(n)` algorithm. For a largish `n` like 600851475143 (about 6*10^11), that is bound to take long.

You need to change the algorithm. When you have found a pair of divisors (both larger than 1), factorise them both recursively. If the smaller of the found factors is 1, that is a prime factor.

Doing that (forgive the bad style, I barely know ruby):

```
#Fermat's factorization method

def get_largest_prime n
    t=(Math.sqrt(n)+1).floor
    k=0
    prime_numbers=[]
    while (t+k)<n
        element = (t+k)**2-n
        if is_integer? Math.sqrt(element)
            #store prime numbers
            a = t+k+Math.sqrt(element)
            b = t+k-Math.sqrt(element)
            if b == 1
                prime_numbers << a
                break
            end
            prime_numbers += get_largest_prime a
            prime_numbers += get_largest_prime b
            break
            #puts "Prime Factors of #{n} are: #{t+k+Math.sqrt(element)} and #{t+k-Math.sqrt(element)}"
        end
        k+=1
    end
  return prime_numbers
end

#making sure 450.0 is 450, for example.
def is_integer? number
    number.to_i == number ? true : false
end

a = get_largest_prime 600851475143
puts "Prime Factors: "+a.to_s
```

solves the given problem quickly.

However, it will still take a long time for numbers that have no divisors close to the square root.

The standard factorisation by trial division has much better worst-case behaviour (`O(sqrt(n)` worst case). A mixed approach can be slightly faster than pure trial division, though.

Answer (score 1):

Two effects here:

1) When an integer gets larger than 2**31 in Ruby, it uses a different, and slower, representation

2) There are no known factorisation algorithms that don't eventually perform badly once the number gets large enough - technically they all get slower worse than any polynomial of the (number of digits of) the number you want to factorise.

You could speed things up by using

```
Math.sqrt(element)
```

less. Assign result of it to a variable, before all the tests. Note this will not "fix" your problem. Ultimately it won't run fast enough above a certain number - even if you transferred everything to C (although you might squeeze out a couple of extra digits before C got slow)

Comment: #2 is a very misguided answer.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Would it be safer to say they scale badly in general; I thought general case factorisation was NP-complete?

Comment: OK, a look on Wikipedia suggests it might be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate but there is no proof

Comment: Factorization complexity is not yet known.   To say they scale badly in general is also very broad, without evidence to support the claim it is equivalent to "just saying words".  I would remove that statement, and perhaps point OP to things such as the general number field sieve.

Comment: How about "there is no known polynomial-time algorithm"? There may be more efficient approaches, which I think you seem to be in a better position to answer than me. Ultimately you cannot point to OP to something that can cope with any number in reasonable time - if they have an upper bound number they'd like to check, that might be useful to know

Comment: I agree if they supplied an upper bound it would allow us to point directly to what OP needs.  And yes, if you change it to your latest statement I would agree and give you the points.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27646/discussion-between-neil-slater-and-woot4moo)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you can try the code below.

```
def prime_factor limit
    (2..Math.sqrt(limit).to_i).inject([]) do |memo, var|
        memo << var if limit % var == 0 and !memo.any? {|d| var % d == 0}
        memo
    end
end
prime_result = prime_factor 600851475143
puts prime_result.max
```

Answer (score 0):

The less loops you use, the faster your code will run ;-) (less cpu cycles). Try to do everything recursively like here [on this program that finds the largest prime factor](https://github.com/RoboEvangelist/Project-Euler/blob/master/C%2B%2B_solutions/problem3.cpp)